# Fancybox for Wordpress - dynamically resize width based on content

Tags: wordpress, resize, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox for Wordpress to display a form.

Within the fancybox is a div with id "popup1", which contains the form.
When the user submits the form, #popup1 disappears, and #popup2 appears. div#popup2 just has a little "Thank you" message that is very short.

The height of the fancybox window automatically resizes to fit the height of the content when I switch from popup1 to popup2, but I want the WIDTH of fancybox window to shrink also. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us a link to look at?

Comment: http://www.ingeniusprep.com/testing-popup/

Comment: Is the content being called from an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You have several handlers to flip from one pop-up to another like

```
$("#popup4-BA").slideDown("slow");
```

Try adding the fancybox (v1.3.4) method `$.fancybox.resize()` after completing the animation like

```
$("#popup4-BA").slideDown("slow", function(){
    $.fancybox.resize();
});
```

... you may need to do this in every handler.

Some Notes:

- you first pop-up has a fixed `width` so you may need to try removing it and set the css `width` property to `auto`.
- since you are using fancybox v1.3.4 with `inline` content, you need to be aware of this **[BUG](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/-re22BoXOzM)** and workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it out and set the width to auto, but it doesn't seem to be working... the second popup is the same width as the first popup, even though it has different content.